# Android - ScrollView Issue

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview

I'm having some trouble with how scrollviews handle content being added to them. Here are two screenshots of my app, once where I add an expandlistview to a scrollview which is nested inside a LinearLayout, and then another where I remove the scrollview. YOu'll notice that when there is no scrollview the content height is maintained. How can I achieve this with a scrollview?

This has the scrollview

[image: With ScrollView]

This doesn't have the scrollview

[image: Without ScrollView]

Here is my layout for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3F3F3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="25dip">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridViewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:background="#61BF1A"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/store"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/store"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/store_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/store"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/store"
                    android:ems="8"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Freshii Woodbridge"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/change_store_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:ems="4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:text="@string/change_store"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I dynamically appended ExpandedListViews to the "gridViewLayout" Linear Layout. Any ideas why the scenario with the scrollview happens and how I can fix it?

---- ExpandlistView Layout ----

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/gridView2"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: What height are you talking about? Be little explicit.

Comment: I'm assuming the height of the expandedlistviews? I have a feeling the properties of the scrollview is causing this to happen. Essentially I want Screenshot 2 to happen when I add them to a scrollview.

Comment: Do you want the same spacing in expandable listview items as listview items?

Comment: Ya, like I said. I want it to look exactly the same as the screenshot that has no scroll view.

Comment: where's your expandable listview's layout?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you should change the `ScrollView` height to `match_parent'

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Nope. With this, it stopped displaying any of the expandedlistviews.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information re ExpandableListView in general, but lease consider this:

> Note: You cannot use the value wrap_content for the
>   android:layout_height attribute of a ExpandableListView in XML if the
>   parent's size is also not strictly specified (for example, if the
>   parent were ScrollView you could not specify wrap_content since it
>   also can be any length. However, you can use wrap_content if the
>   ExpandableListView parent has a specific size, such as 100 pixels.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Added the layout for the ExpandableListView

Answer (score 0):

Add the margin to top and bottom of your expandable listview.

```
<ExpandableListView
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/gridView2"
android:groupIndicator="@null"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

Edit :

Try `android:dividerHeight="10dp"` it should work.

Comment: Nothing. Still getting the same result

Comment: Yup, didnt work. I refactored my code to no longer use a scrollview, but rather create a nested expandablelistview approach where each parent cell would create another expandablelistview.